# Sorting items from asp:menu datasource

Tags: asp.net, xml

*I haven't been able to find an answer to this elsewhere.*

I have made an XML file which I tend to use as my site navigation provider.
In this XML I've added an attribute to the navigation elements called "Position".

How do I sort the items provided to my `<asp:Menu />` control in ascending order to the Position attribute?

Comment: Not sure if there is an easier way, but Linq is definitely an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

> The XMLDataSource control doesn't support sorting and paging